# access the sources or console window object or events

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm building a chrome extension and I would like to be able to access the sources of console window objects, or possible be able to listen to their events.  I want to know when the user makes changes to either of these and get information about the change.  I spend some time in the API docs and it looks like this isn't possible, but thought I would ask just in case I'm missing something.

Comment: You will have to spoof/hook/proxy these properties in [page context](/a/9517879).

Comment: The page conext can access the DOM, but that doesn't have access to the dev tools windows - unless I'm missing something.

Comment: What exactly are "dev tools windows" and "sources of console window objects"?